# Animate toolBar from another class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, selector, uitoolbar

I'm trying to execute a method that is my SecondViewController from my FirstViewController, and it works, the method is called cuz I see my message(NSLog(@"printSomething")) in the log console. 
The problem is that in that method am trying to move a UIToolBar, but it doesn't.
If I call the method from his own viewController it works, the UIToolBar moves, but when I call it from another viewController...the method is executed, but the UIToolBar  do nothing

FirstViewController.m

```
UIBarButtonItem *flipButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                               initWithTitle:@"Opciones"                                            
                                       style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered 
                                      target:secondViewController
                                      action:@selector(showOptions)];
```

SecondViewController.m

```
-(void)showOptions{
NSLog(@"printSomething");
[self.toolBar setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 40, 320, 50)];
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:.35];
[self.toolBar setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 180, 320, 50)];
[self.toolBar setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

}

Thanks for ur replays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your NSLog statement to this:

```
  NSLog(@"self.toolbar is 0x%x",self.toolBar);
```

and see if the value is non-null.  This is a very common problem - sending a message to a null object is not a runtime error in Objective-C.

Comment: This means that variable is null - it doesn't point anywhere.  You need to provide a valid reference to the toolbar to the second view controller.  You could pass it in as a parameter when you instantiate the second view contoller, and then do    self.toolbar = MyToolbarParameter.